# MouseEvent Listeners/EventTypes for TreeItems

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, listeners

Basically, I have a TreeView

```
TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>();
```

The root

```
TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<String>();
treeView.setRoot(root);
```

And lastly an item inside the root

```
TreeItem<String> item1 = new TreeItem<String>();
root.getChildren().add(item1);
```

(With or without more siblings or adding more children to `item1`)
And what I want to do is add a listener or EventHandler specifically for `item1` (and any siblings) so when a user double clicks on it or changes its value, something happens. I also want to know if there are any of these that show the oldValue and newValue of the TreeItem when it is edited.

The only leads I really have are that it probably has to do with using:

```
root.getChildren().addListeners()...
treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener...
```

or

```
item1.addEventHandler(...
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also want to know if there are any of these that show the oldValue and newValue of the TreeItem when it is edited.

Are you just looking for

```
item1.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // do whatever you need with oldValue and newValue
});
```

?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Now I'm just curious if there is possibly something else for double clicking on a TreeItem.

Comment: For that you need to use a cell factory and register a listener with the cell.